# What does shell_session_history_check do in the default PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using terminal on MacOS High Sierra.

I added `echo PROMPT_COMMAND` to the top of my `.bash_profile` to see the default and I got:

`'shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd'`

---

I don't fully understand what the `shell_session_history_check` actually does. I can't really find a difference with/without it (history from closed shells still show up in `history` in a new shell).

Comment: Where is that function from? It doesn't come with bash. And what does your first paragraph mean? Is it a quote from somewhere? Where?

Comment: Updated 1st paragraph. It’s a Mac specific function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`shell_session_history_check` calls `shell_session_history_enable` which creates a unique log file for each shell session.**

*NOTE: `shell_session_history_check` is a Mac specific function.*

---

Let's break it down.

```
$ declare -f shell_session_history_check
shell_session_history_check () 
{ 
    if [ ${SHELL_SESSION_DID_HISTORY_CHECK:-0} -eq 0 ]; then
        SHELL_SESSION_DID_HISTORY_CHECK=1;
        if shell_session_history_allowed; then
            shell_session_history_enable;
        fi;
        if [ "$PROMPT_COMMAND" = "shell_session_history_check" ]; then
            unset PROMPT_COMMAND;
        else
            if [[ $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ (.*)(; *shell_session_history_check *| *shell_session_history_check *; *)(.*) ]]; then
                PROMPT_COMMAND="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}";
            fi;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

The last `if/else` removes `shell_session_history_check` from the `PROMPT_COMMAND` (assuming your `PROMPT_COMMAND` starts with `shell_session_history_check;`) so that it only runs on the first prompt.

`shell_session_history_allowed` is true by default so basically the real behavior is calling `shell_session_history_enable`.

```
$ declare -f shell_session_history_enable
shell_session_history_enable () 
{ 
    ( umask 077;
    /usr/bin/touch "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW" );
    HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW";
    SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1
}
```

This function overwrites the [default value](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html) of `HISTFILE` (`~/.bash_history`) and sets the `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY` to `1` (true).

So this question boils down to: **Why is the history saved even though `HISTFILE` isn't set to a unique file name?**

Well it still functions the same way. Once the shell exits, it appends to `~/.bash_history`. The difference is that **you don't have unique files logging each session**.

**Why would I want unique files logging each session?**

Check out this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/):

> (~/.bash_sessions/) is used to store HISTFILE's and .session files
> that are unique to sessions. If $BASH_SESSION or $TERM_SESSION_ID is
> set upon launching the shell (i.e. if Terminal is resuming from a
> saved state), the associated HISTFILE is merged into the current one,
> and the .session file is ran. Session saving is facilitated by means
> of an EXIT trap being set for a function bash_update_session_state.
>
> Essentially, this lays the groundwork for us to be able to extend
> Terminal's session-resuming using our own rc files. By implementing
> our own extension of bash_update_session_state, we can, say, add
> functionality to the .session files that are run upon resume.